# NullPointerException while executing cap write_permissions task from tutorial

Tags: capistrano

I'm seeing an NPE when trying to execute the `check_write_permissions` task from the [Capistrano website](http://capistranorb.com/documentation/getting-started/cold-start/#2-writing-our-first-cap-task-to-formalize-this-into-a-check).

The stage file itself is straightforward:

```
server "demo.ourapp.com", user: "deployuser", roles: %w{app db web}

set :branch, "dev"
set :deployment, "demo"
set :rails_env, "production"

role :app, "demo.ourapp.com"
role :web, "demo.ourapp.com"
role :db,  "demo.ourapp.com", :primary => true

set :repository,  "git@github.com:ouruser/ourapp.git"

set :deploy_to, "/opt/companyname/ourapp-demo"

set :puma_bind,       "unix://#{shared_path}/tmp/sockets/#{fetch(:application)}-puma.sock"
set :puma_state,      "#{shared_path}/tmp/pids/puma.state"
set :puma_pid,        "#{shared_path}/tmp/pids/puma.pid"
set :puma_access_log, "#{release_path}/log/puma.error.log"
set :puma_error_log,  "#{release_path}/log/puma.access.log"
set :puma_preload_app, true
set :puma_worker_timeout, nil
```

Upon executing `bundle exec cap deploy this:stage check_write_permissions`, I get the following error:

```
$ bundle exec cap this:stage check_write_permissions --trace                                       ‹jruby-9.1.12.0›
** Invoke this:stage (first_time)
** Execute this:stage
** Invoke load:defaults (first_time)
** Execute load:defaults
** Invoke bundler:map_bins (first_time)
** Execute bundler:map_bins
** Invoke deploy:set_rails_env (first_time)
** Execute deploy:set_rails_env
** Invoke deploy:set_linked_dirs (first_time)
** Execute deploy:set_linked_dirs
** Invoke deploy:set_rails_env
** Invoke check_write_permissions (first_time)
** Execute check_write_permissions
cap aborted!
SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: Exception while executing as deployuser@demo.ourapp.com:
/Users/srdjan/.bundle/jruby/2.3.0/gems/sshkit-1.14.0/lib/sshkit/runners/parallel.rb:15:in `block in execute'
Java::JavaLang::NullPointerException:
org.jruby.ext.openssl.PKeyEC$Point.initialize(PKeyEC.java:845)
org.jruby.ext.openssl.PKeyEC$Point$INVOKER$i$0$0$initialize.call(PKeyEC$Point$INVOKER$i$0$0$initialize.gen)
org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.JavaMethod$JavaMethodN.call(JavaMethod.java:725)
org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:368)
org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.callBlock(CachingCallSite.java:205)
org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:209)
org.jruby.RubyClass.newInstance(RubyClass.java:1008)
org.jruby.RubyClass$INVOKER$i$newInstance.call(RubyClass$INVOKER$i$newInstance.gen)
org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DynamicMethod.call(DynamicMethod.java:208)
org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:358)
org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:195)
org.jruby.ir.interpreter.InterpreterEngine.processCall(InterpreterEngine.java:323)
org.jruby.ir.interpreter.StartupInterpreterEngine.interpret(StartupInterpreterEngine.java:73)
org.jruby.ir.interpreter.InterpreterEngine.interpret(InterpreterEngine.java:89)
org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.MixedModeIRMethod.INTERPRET_METHOD(MixedModeIRMethod.java:214)
org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.MixedModeIRMethod.call(MixedModeIRMethod.java:200)
org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DynamicMethod.call(DynamicMethod.java:208)
org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:358)
org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:195)
org.jruby.ir.interpreter.InterpreterEngine.processCall(InterpreterEngine.java:323)
org.jruby.ir.interpreter.StartupInterpreterEngine.interpret(StartupInterpreterEngine.java:73)
org.jruby.ir.interpreter.InterpreterEngine.interpret(InterpreterEngine.java:83)
org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.MixedModeIRMethod.INTERPRET_METHOD(MixedModeIRMethod.java:179)
org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.MixedModeIRMethod.call(MixedModeIRMethod.java:165)
org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DynamicMethod.call(DynamicMethod.java:200)
org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:161)
org.jruby.ir.interpreter.InterpreterEngine.processCall(InterpreterEngine.java:314)
org.jruby.ir.interpreter.StartupInterpreterEngine.interpret(StartupInterpreterEngine.java:73)
org.jruby.ir.interpreter.InterpreterEngine.interpret(InterpreterEngine.java:77)
org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.MixedModeIRMethod.INTERPRET_METHOD(MixedModeIRMethod.java:144)
org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.MixedModeIRMethod.call(MixedModeIRMethod.java:130)
org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DynamicMethod.call(DynamicMethod.java:192)
org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:129)
org.jruby.ir.interpreter.InterpreterEngine.processCall(InterpreterEngine.java:339)
org.jruby.ir.interpreter.StartupInterpreterEngine.interpret(StartupInterpreterEngine.java:73)
org.jruby.ir.interpreter.InterpreterEngine.interpret(InterpreterEngine.java:83)
org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.MixedModeIRMethod.INTERPRET_METHOD(MixedModeIRMethod.java:179)
org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.MixedModeIRMethod.call(MixedModeIRMethod.java:165)
org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DynamicMethod.call(DynamicMethod.java:200)
org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:161)
org.jruby.ir.interpreter.InterpreterEngine.processCall(InterpreterEngine.java:314)
org.jruby.ir.interpreter.StartupInterpreterEngine.interpret(StartupInterpreterEngine.java:73)
org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.MixedModeIRMethod.INTERPRET_METHOD(MixedModeIRMethod.java:109)
org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.MixedModeIRMethod.call(MixedModeIRMethod.java:95)
org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.callBlock(CachingCallSite.java:77)
org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:83)
org.jruby.ir.instructions.CallBase.interpret(CallBase.java:428)
org.jruby.ir.interpreter.InterpreterEngine.processCall(InterpreterEngine.java:355)
org.jruby.ir.interpreter.StartupInterpreterEngine.interpret(StartupInterpreterEngine.java:73)
org.jruby.ir.interpreter.Interpreter.INTERPRET_BLOCK(Interpreter.java:132)
org.jruby.runtime.MixedModeIRBlockBody.commonYieldPath(MixedModeIRBlockBody.java:148)
org.jruby.runtime.IRBlockBody.doYield(IRBlockBody.java:186)
org.jruby.runtime.BlockBody.yield(BlockBody.java:116)
org.jruby.runtime.Block.yield(Block.java:165)
org.jruby.RubyIO.each_lineInternal(RubyIO.java:3282)
org.jruby.RubyIO.each_line(RubyIO.java:3295)
org.jruby.RubyIO$INVOKER$i$0$1$each_line.call(RubyIO$INVOKER$i$0$1$each_line.gen)
org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:298)
org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.callBlock(CachingCallSite.java:79)
org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:83)
org.jruby.ir.instructions.CallBase.interpret(CallBase.java:428)
org.jruby.ir.interpreter.InterpreterEngine.processCall(InterpreterEngine.java:355)
org.jruby.ir.interpreter.StartupInterpreterEngine.interpret(StartupInterpreterEngine.java:73)
org.jruby.ir.interpreter.Interpreter.INTERPRET_BLOCK(Interpreter.java:132)
org.jruby.runtime.MixedModeIRBlockBody.commonYieldPath(MixedModeIRBlockBody.java:148)
org.jruby.runtime.IRBlockBody.doYield(IRBlockBody.java:186)
org.jruby.runtime.BlockBody.yield(BlockBody.java:116)
org.jruby.runtime.Block.yield(Block.java:165)
org.jruby.RubyIO.ensureYieldClose(RubyIO.java:1163)
org.jruby.RubyIO.open(RubyIO.java:1156)
org.jruby.RubyIO$INVOKER$s$0$0$open.call(RubyIO$INVOKER$s$0$0$open.gen)
org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DynamicMethod.call(DynamicMethod.java:204)
org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:348)
org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.callBlock(CachingCallSite.java:173)
org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:177)
org.jruby.ir.interpreter.InterpreterEngine.processCall(InterpreterEngine.java:332)
org.jruby.ir.interpreter.StartupInterpreterEngine.interpret(StartupInterpreterEngine.java:73)
org.jruby.ir.interpreter.Interpreter.INTERPRET_BLOCK(Interpreter.java:132)
org.jruby.runtime.MixedModeIRBlockBody.commonYieldPath(MixedModeIRBlockBody.java:148)
org.jruby.runtime.IRBlockBody.yieldSpecific(IRBlockBody.java:84)
org.jruby.runtime.Block.yieldSpecific(Block.java:134)
org.jruby.ext.thread.Mutex.synchronize(Mutex.java:148)
org.jruby.ext.thread.Mutex$INVOKER$i$0$0$synchronize.call(Mutex$INVOKER$i$0$0$synchronize.gen)
org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.JavaMethod$JavaMethodZeroBlock.call(JavaMethod.java:498)
org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.callBlock(CachingCallSite.java:77)
org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:83)
org.jruby.ir.instructions.CallBase.interpret(CallBase.java:428)
org.jruby.ir.interpreter.InterpreterEngine.processCall(InterpreterEngine.java:355)
org.jruby.ir.interpreter.StartupInterpreterEngine.interpret(StartupInterpreterEngine.java:73)
org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.MixedModeIRMethod.INTERPRET_METHOD(MixedModeIRMethod.java:109)
org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.MixedModeIRMethod.call(MixedModeIRMethod.java:95)
org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.AliasMethod.call(AliasMethod.java:101)
org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:298)
org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.callBlock(CachingCallSite.java:79)
org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:83)
org.jruby.ir.instructions.CallBase.interpret(CallBase.java:428)
org.jruby.ir.interpreter.InterpreterEngine.processCall(InterpreterEngine.java:355)
org.jruby.ir.interpreter.StartupInterpreterEngine.interpret(StartupInterpreterEngine.java:73)
org.jruby.ir.interpreter.InterpreterEngine.interpret(InterpreterEngine.java:77)
org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.MixedModeIRMethod.INTERPRET_METHOD(MixedModeIRMethod.java:144)
org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.MixedModeIRMethod.call(MixedModeIRMethod.java:130)
org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DynamicMethod.call(DynamicMethod.java:192)
org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:318)
org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:131)
org.jruby.ir.interpreter.InterpreterEngine.processCall(InterpreterEngine.java:339)
org.jruby.ir.interpreter.StartupInterpreterEngine.interpret(StartupInterpreterEngine.java:73)
org.jruby.ir.interpreter.InterpreterEngine.interpret(InterpreterEngine.java:83)
org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.MixedModeIRMethod.INTERPRET_METHOD(MixedModeIRMethod.java:179)
org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.MixedModeIRMethod.call(MixedModeIRMethod.java:165)
org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DynamicMethod.call(DynamicMethod.java:200)
org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:338)
org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:163)
org.jruby.ir.interpreter.InterpreterEngine.processCall(InterpreterEngine.java:314)
org.jruby.ir.interpreter.StartupInterpreterEngine.interpret(StartupInterpreterEngine.java:73)
org.jruby.ir.interpreter.Interpreter.INTERPRET_BLOCK(Interpreter.java:132)
org.jruby.runtime.MixedModeIRBlockBody.commonYieldPath(MixedModeIRBlockBody.java:148)
org.jruby.runtime.IRBlockBody.doYield(IRBlockBody.java:186)
org.jruby.runtime.BlockBody.yield(BlockBody.java:116)
org.jruby.runtime.Block.yield(Block.java:165)
org.jruby.RubyArray.collect(RubyArray.java:2472)
org.jruby.RubyArray.map19(RubyArray.java:2486)
org.jruby.RubyArray$INVOKER$i$0$0$map19.call(RubyArray$INVOKER$i$0$0$map19.gen)
org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.JavaMethod$JavaMethodZeroBlock.call(JavaMethod.java:498)
org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:298)
org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.callBlock(CachingCallSite.java:79)
org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:83)
org.jruby.ir.instructions.CallBase.interpret(CallBase.java:428)
org.jruby.ir.interpreter.InterpreterEngine.processCall(InterpreterEngine.java:355)
org.jruby.ir.interpreter.StartupInterpreterEngine.interpret(StartupInterpreterEngine.java:73)
org.jruby.ir.interpreter.InterpreterEngine.interpret(InterpreterEngine.java:89)
org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.MixedModeIRMethod.INTERPRET_METHOD(MixedModeIRMethod.java:214)
org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.MixedModeIRMethod.call(MixedModeIRMethod.java:200)
org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DynamicMethod.call(DynamicMethod.java:208)
org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:358)
org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:195)
org.jruby.ir.interpreter.InterpreterEngine.processCall(InterpreterEngine.java:323)
org.jruby.ir.interpreter.StartupInterpreterEngine.interpret(StartupInterpreterEngine.java:73)
org.jruby.ir.interpreter.InterpreterEngine.interpret(InterpreterEngine.java:77)
org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.MixedModeIRMethod.INTERPRET_METHOD(MixedModeIRMethod.java:144)
org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.MixedModeIRMethod.call(MixedModeIRMethod.java:130)
org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DynamicMethod.call(DynamicMethod.java:192)
org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:318)
org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:131)
org.jruby.ir.interpreter.InterpreterEngine.processCall(InterpreterEngine.java:339)
org.jruby.ir.interpreter.StartupInterpreterEngine.interpret(StartupInterpreterEngine.java:73)
org.jruby.ir.interpreter.InterpreterEngine.interpret(InterpreterEngine.java:77)
org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.MixedModeIRMethod.INTERPRET_METHOD(MixedModeIRMethod.java:144)
org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.MixedModeIRMethod.call(MixedModeIRMethod.java:130)
org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DynamicMethod.call(DynamicMethod.java:192)
org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:318)
org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:131)
org.jruby.ir.interpreter.InterpreterEngine.processCall(InterpreterEngine.java:339)
org.jruby.ir.interpreter.StartupInterpreterEngine.interpret(StartupInterpreterEngine.java:73)
org.jruby.ir.interpreter.InterpreterEngine.interpret(InterpreterEngine.java:89)
org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.MixedModeIRMethod.INTERPRET_METHOD(MixedModeIRMethod.java:214)
org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.MixedModeIRMethod.call(MixedModeIRMethod.java:200)
org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:368)
org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.callBlock(CachingCallSite.java:205)
org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:209)
org.jruby.RubyClass.newInstance(RubyClass.java:1008)
org.jruby.RubyClass$INVOKER$i$newInstance.call(RubyClass$INVOKER$i$newInstance.gen)
org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DynamicMethod.call(DynamicMethod.java:208)
org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:358)
org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:195)
org.jruby.ir.interpreter.InterpreterEngine.processCall(InterpreterEngine.java:323)
org.jruby.ir.interpreter.StartupInterpreterEngine.interpret(StartupInterpreterEngine.java:73)
org.jruby.ir.interpreter.InterpreterEngine.interpret(InterpreterEngine.java:89)
org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.MixedModeIRMethod.INTERPRET_METHOD(MixedModeIRMethod.java:214)
org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.MixedModeIRMethod.call(MixedModeIRMethod.java:200)
org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:368)
org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.callBlock(CachingCallSite.java:205)
org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:209)
org.jruby.RubyClass.newInstance(RubyClass.java:1008)
org.jruby.RubyClass$INVOKER$i$newInstance.call(RubyClass$INVOKER$i$newInstance.gen)
org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DynamicMethod.call(DynamicMethod.java:208)
org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:358)
org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:195)
org.jruby.ir.interpreter.InterpreterEngine.processCall(InterpreterEngine.java:323)
org.jruby.ir.interpreter.StartupInterpreterEngine.interpret(StartupInterpreterEngine.java:73)
org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.MixedModeIRMethod.INTERPRET_METHOD(MixedModeIRMethod.java:109)
org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.MixedModeIRMethod.call(MixedModeIRMethod.java:95)
org.jruby.RubyMethod.call(RubyMethod.java:127)
org.jruby.RubyMethod$INVOKER$i$call.call(RubyMethod$INVOKER$i$call.gen)
org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:298)
org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.callBlock(CachingCallSite.java:79)
org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:83)
org.jruby.ir.instructions.CallBase.interpret(CallBase.java:428)
org.jruby.ir.interpreter.InterpreterEngine.processCall(InterpreterEngine.java:355)
org.jruby.ir.interpreter.StartupInterpreterEngine.interpret(StartupInterpreterEngine.java:73)
org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.MixedModeIRMethod.INTERPRET_METHOD(MixedModeIRMethod.java:109)
org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.MixedModeIRMethod.call(MixedModeIRMethod.java:95)
org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:298)
org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.callBlock(CachingCallSite.java:79)
org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:83)
org.jruby.ir.instructions.CallBase.interpret(CallBase.java:428)
org.jruby.ir.interpreter.InterpreterEngine.processCall(InterpreterEngine.java:355)
org.jruby.ir.interpreter.StartupInterpreterEngine.interpret(StartupInterpreterEngine.java:73)
org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.MixedModeIRMethod.INTERPRET_METHOD(MixedModeIRMethod.java:109)
org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.MixedModeIRMethod.call(MixedModeIRMethod.java:95)
org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:298)
org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.callBlock(CachingCallSite.java:79)
org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:83)
org.jruby.ir.instructions.CallBase.interpret(CallBase.java:428)
org.jruby.ir.interpreter.InterpreterEngine.processCall(InterpreterEngine.java:355)
org.jruby.ir.interpreter.StartupInterpreterEngine.interpret(StartupInterpreterEngine.java:73)
org.jruby.ir.interpreter.InterpreterEngine.interpret(InterpreterEngine.java:83)
org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.MixedModeIRMethod.INTERPRET_METHOD(MixedModeIRMethod.java:179)
org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.MixedModeIRMethod.call(MixedModeIRMethod.java:165)
org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DynamicMethod.call(DynamicMethod.java:200)
org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:338)
org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:163)
org.jruby.ir.interpreter.InterpreterEngine.processCall(InterpreterEngine.java:314)
org.jruby.ir.interpreter.StartupInterpreterEngine.interpret(StartupInterpreterEngine.java:73)
org.jruby.ir.interpreter.Interpreter.INTERPRET_BLOCK(Interpreter.java:132)
org.jruby.runtime.MixedModeIRBlockBody.commonYieldPath(MixedModeIRBlockBody.java:148)
org.jruby.runtime.IRBlockBody.doYield(IRBlockBody.java:186)
org.jruby.runtime.BlockBody.yield(BlockBody.java:116)
org.jruby.runtime.Block.yield(Block.java:165)
org.jruby.RubyKernel.tap(RubyKernel.java:1747)
org.jruby.RubyKernel$INVOKER$s$0$0$tap.call(RubyKernel$INVOKER$s$0$0$tap.gen)
org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.JavaMethod$JavaMethodZeroBlock.call(JavaMethod.java:498)
org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:298)
org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.callBlock(CachingCallSite.java:79)
org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:83)
org.jruby.ir.instructions.CallBase.interpret(CallBase.java:428)
org.jruby.ir.interpreter.InterpreterEngine.processCall(InterpreterEngine.java:355)
org.jruby.ir.interpreter.StartupInterpreterEngine.interpret(StartupInterpreterEngine.java:73)
org.jruby.ir.interpreter.InterpreterEngine.interpret(InterpreterEngine.java:89)
org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.MixedModeIRMethod.INTERPRET_METHOD(MixedModeIRMethod.java:214)
org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.MixedModeIRMethod.call(MixedModeIRMethod.java:200)
org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DynamicMethod.call(DynamicMethod.java:208)
org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:358)
org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:195)
org.jruby.ir.interpreter.InterpreterEngine.processCall(InterpreterEngine.java:323)
org.jruby.ir.interpreter.StartupInterpreterEngine.interpret(StartupInterpreterEngine.java:73)
org.jruby.ir.interpreter.InterpreterEngine.interpret(InterpreterEngine.java:83)
org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.MixedModeIRMethod.INTERPRET_METHOD(MixedModeIRMethod.java:179)
org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.MixedModeIRMethod.call(MixedModeIRMethod.java:165)
org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DynamicMethod.call(DynamicMethod.java:200)
org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:338)
org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:163)
org.jruby.ir.interpreter.InterpreterEngine.processCall(InterpreterEngine.java:314)
org.jruby.ir.interpreter.StartupInterpreterEngine.interpret(StartupInterpreterEngine.java:73)
org.jruby.ir.interpreter.Interpreter.INTERPRET_BLOCK(Interpreter.java:132)
org.jruby.runtime.MixedModeIRBlockBody.commonYieldPath(MixedModeIRBlockBody.java:148)
org.jruby.runtime.IRBlockBody.doYield(IRBlockBody.java:193)
org.jruby.runtime.BlockBody.yield(BlockBody.java:125)
org.jruby.runtime.Block.yieldNonArray(Block.java:169)
org.jruby.RubyBasicObject.yieldUnder(RubyBasicObject.java:1751)
org.jruby.RubyBasicObject.instance_exec19(RubyBasicObject.java:1728)
org.jruby.RubyBasicObject$INVOKER$i$0$3$instance_exec19.call(RubyBasicObject$INVOKER$i$0$3$instance_exec19.gen)
org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DynamicMethod.call(DynamicMethod.java:204)
org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:348)
org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.callBlock(CachingCallSite.java:173)
org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:177)
org.jruby.ir.interpreter.InterpreterEngine.processCall(InterpreterEngine.java:332)
org.jruby.ir.interpreter.StartupInterpreterEngine.interpret(StartupInterpreterEngine.java:73)
org.jruby.ir.interpreter.InterpreterEngine.interpret(InterpreterEngine.java:77)
org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.MixedModeIRMethod.INTERPRET_METHOD(MixedModeIRMethod.java:144)
org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.MixedModeIRMethod.call(MixedModeIRMethod.java:130)
org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DynamicMethod.call(DynamicMethod.java:192)
org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:318)
org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:131)
org.jruby.ir.interpreter.InterpreterEngine.processCall(InterpreterEngine.java:339)
org.jruby.ir.interpreter.StartupInterpreterEngine.interpret(StartupInterpreterEngine.java:73)
org.jruby.ir.interpreter.Interpreter.INTERPRET_BLOCK(Interpreter.java:132)
org.jruby.runtime.MixedModeIRBlockBody.commonYieldPath(MixedModeIRBlockBody.java:148)
org.jruby.runtime.IRBlockBody.call(IRBlockBody.java:73)
org.jruby.runtime.Block.call(Block.java:124)
org.jruby.RubyProc.call(RubyProc.java:289)
org.jruby.RubyProc.call(RubyProc.java:246)
org.jruby.internal.runtime.RubyRunnable.run(RubyRunnable.java:104)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Tasks: TOP => check_write_permissions
```

I am using JRuby 9.1.12.0, Capistrano 3.8.2. I've anonymized the info, but the `deployuser` does have passwordless SSH access.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Cross posted to https://github.com/capistrano/sshkit/issues/405

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A search for `org.jruby.ext.openssl.PKeyEC$Point.initialize(PKeyEC.java:845)` turned up this: https://github.com/jruby/jruby-openssl/issues/105 which suggests this as a workaround:

```rb
Net::SSH::Transport::Algorithms::ALGORITHMS.values.each { |algs| algs.reject! { |a| a =~ /^ecd(sa|h)-sha2/ } }
Net::SSH::KnownHosts::SUPPORTED_TYPE.reject! { |t| t =~ /^ecd(sa|h)-sha2/ }
```

Does this help at all?

Comment: Adding these two lines to deploy.rb helped me. Thanks.